# How to navigate to root of a children in Angular2 router?

Tags: angular

I have the following router in my App.ts:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', redirectTo: ['Login']},
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: '/users/...', name:'Users', component: UsersComponent}
])
```

And in my UsersComponent I have defined its children:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/addUser', name: 'Add User', component: UserAddComponent},
    {path: '/editUser', name: 'Edit User', component: UserEditComponent}
])
```

My question is: when I am trying to navigate to JUST `/users/`, I have the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Link "["Users"]" does not resolve to a terminal instruction. in [['Users'] in NavigationComponent@5:20]
```

How can I access just users state (the html defined in UsersComponent)?

Comment: What do you use to navigate? Link, code, ...?

Comment: I use the following: [routerLink]="['Users']"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make new component that just handles routing `UserRoute` and use that in App:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', redirectTo: ['Login']},
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: '/users/...', name:'Users', component: UsersRoute}
])

// users-route.ts
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'UsersRoot', component: UsersComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/addUser', name: 'Add User', component: UserAddComponent},
    {path: '/editUser', name: 'Edit User', component: UserEditComponent}
])
```

You can name root route for users whatever you want, because of the `useAsDefault` option `['/Users']` route will terminate at `UsersRoot`.

Comment: You just need to get used to the route components vs view components. `UsersRoute` needs to have `<router-outlet>`, any common template code is optional..

Answer (score 1):

You either need to set `useAsDefault: true` in one of the child routes of `Users` or specify a child route directly in the link

```
[routerLink]="['/Users', `Add User']"
```

Comment: It still throws me the same error: Link "["/Users"]" does not resolve to a terminal instruction. in [['/Users'] in NavigationComponent@5:20]

Comment: After your update - so there is no way to access UsersCompontent, without going to its children? that doesnt seem right

Comment: If you specify a route as parent route `someroute/...` then you need to specify a child route.